# Power management shortcut

Tags: 11.10, power-management

I am looking for a custom shortcut for showing power managemnt ( like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> in ubuntu 10.10 that showed some tools for shutdown, suspend , restart , ... )

I don't know which command does this. for example for showing system monitoring custom shortcut command is gnome-system-monitor. but I don't know what is for power.

Thanks,
M.Varmazyar

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command you are looking for is `gnome-session-quit --power-off`:

[image]

This is the same dialog as in 11.04, but it has been redesigned.